# Find with filter and map

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter

I have the following statement in MongoDB:

```
db.getCollection('Forms').find({"Id": { $nin: db.Forms.find({"Status": "DELETE" }, {_id:0, Id:1}).map(function (fr) { return fr.Id;} ) }})
```

The Forms collection is an append only Collection that can have ADD, UPDATE and DELETE Status records written to it and what this "select" does is return all of the Forms from the collection that don't have a DELETE record.

The question is: how do I go about writing the filter using the MongoDB Driver? I tried the following, it returns an empty list:

```
new BsonDocument("Id", "{ $nin: db.Forms.find({\"Status\": \"DELETE\" }, {_id:0, Id:1}).map(function (fr) { return fr.Id;} ) }");
```

Below is an example of some of the rows in the collection, I have excluded most of the fields and just selected the relevant fields here:

```
/* 1 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55caeb15b33c2d1ff84a618c"),"Id" : "55cae279b33c2d0c2831340c","Status" : "DELETE"}
/* 2 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55cae279b33c2d0c2831340c"),"Id" : "55cae279b33c2d0c2831340c","Status" : "ADD"}
/* 3 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55cae263b33c2d0c2831340b"),"Id" : "55cae21eb33c2d1c187fb2b8","Status" : "DELETE"}
/* 4 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55cae21eb33c2d1c187fb2b8"),"Id" : "55cae21eb33c2d1c187fb2b8","Status" : "ADD"}
/* 5 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55cae200b33c2d1c187fb2b6"),"Id" : "55cae177b33c2d1c187fb2b1","Status" : "DELETE"}
/* 6 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55cae192b33c2d1c187fb2b2"),"Id" : "55cae177b33c2d1c187fb2b1","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 7 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55cae177b33c2d1c187fb2b1"),"Id" : "55cae177b33c2d1c187fb2b1","Status" : "ADD"}
/* 8 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55cad0bcb33c2d1040d49d25"),"Id" : "55c9ec2bb33c2d2d04126cf7","Status" : "DELETE"}
/* 9 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c9f5f0b33c2c27947ef05b"),"Id" : "55c9ec2bb33c2d2d04126cf7","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 10 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c9f5c5b33c2c27947ef05a"),"Id" : "55c9ec2bb33c2d2d04126cf7","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 19 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c9ec2bb33c2d2d04126cf7"),"Id" : "55c9ec2bb33c2d2d04126cf7","Status" : "ADD"}
...
/* 44 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c32785b33c2c206014caf0"),"Id" : "55c08ea1b33c2d24f0aaf697","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 45 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c31762b33c2c235cbef0f9"),"Id" : "55c08ea1b33c2d24f0aaf697","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 46 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c31304b33c2c235cbef0e9"),"Id" : "55c08ea1b33c2d24f0aaf697","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 47 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c2071fb33c2d0d1ca701fe"),"Id" : "55c08ea1b33c2d24f0aaf697","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 48 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c1ee9db33c2d2090685c29"),"Id" : "55c08ea1b33c2d24f0aaf697","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 49 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c1e267b33c2d2090685bff"),"Id" : "55c08ea1b33c2d24f0aaf697","Status" : "UPDATE"}
/* 50 */{"_id" : ObjectId("55c1b2eeb33c2c1f0cb151c2"),"Id" : "55c08ea1b33c2d24f0aaf697","Status" : "UPDATE"}
```

So the select needs to exclude all the Forms (not rows) that have "DELETE" entries - i.e. as soon as there's a DELETE record for the Form, it must be excluded from the list.

To clarify: The _id field is a unique ID per row, and Id is the ID for the Form that I'm using in the select.

**Edit:** While @BlakesSeven's suggested duplicate answer explains to me that I cannot call functions "inline" like I tried to do, the question still stands: How do I write this line of code as a MapReduce *using the MongoDB C# Driver*:

```
db.getCollection('Forms').find({"Id": { $nin: db.Forms.find({"Status": "DELETE" }, {_id:0, Id:1}).map(function (fr) { return fr.Id;} ) }})
```

Comment: Can you explain why your suggestion "obviously "doesn't work?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Sorry, that was a bit unclear: it just returns an empty list, i.e. the filter as it is there doesn't return anything. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Is your Status field an array? Is there a reason to select Ids first and filter by them instead of filter by status immediately?

Comment: @FireAlkazar: Nope, each Form can have multiple rows with different statuses - so the same form can have five rows with the same Id, but the statuses are different, i.e. the first one when it was added, then updates to it and finally a delete if relevant. And once a DELETE row has been inserted, I want to exclude that Form from the list. I hope that makes sense? I'll put together a list to show the data quickly.

Comment: @JohannMarx yes, it is. It was not obvious that documents(rows) have the same Ids.

Comment: How can we explain to you in rational terms that you cannot submit statements that include embedded JavaScipt sytax from the shel withing other langauges. And also that what you "think is happening" in the shell is not what actually happens when you do this. It's a sad fact that judging by the upvotes received so far there are at least that many other people in the world with the same misconceptions as your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom functions calculated columns mongodb projection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620582/custom-functions-calculated-columns-mongodb-projection)

Comment: @BlakesSeven - I'm new to MongoDB, I'm learning as I go and "You cannot submit statements that include embedded JavaScipt sytax from the shell within other languages" makes sense to me. That's why I asked for the correct way of doing it using the C# Driver. I started looking at MapReduce and it looks like that might do the trick, but I'm still not sure how to do what I want to do here using MapReduce. There's only one way for me to find out these things and that's by asking questions. Thank you for your answer, albeit a bit abrasively given.

Comment: Excuse me, but I submitted  "duplicate" question link about the same misconceptions you have that also nicely "explains" what is wrong here, and with the further misconceptions you carry into your last comment. So, "Thank you very much" would be a far more appropriate response. You would do well to "learn" from reading the material

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and help @BlakesSeven and I read the Duplicate Answer post right after I replied, but it still doesn't quite answer my question/I still don't quite understand. I'm trying to learn from what I'm reading, but I have very very little exposure to MongoDB and that's why I asked for help, but starting an answer with "How can we explain to you in rational terms" straight off the bat is uncalled for, don't you think? Anyway, I do thank you very much for the answer and I'll keep on reading and trying.

Comment: You have to understand my position here when your question is "upvoted" for what is really only a "misunderstanding" of the process by yourself and others. So don't take offence, even if it is admittedly part in "exasperation" as why do people still not understand this. Therefore I would suggest "re-reading" the answer given there until it sinks in. What you see is the shell is the "result" of one query operation ( as the shell allows ) being "transposed" into the form just like a variable when it is consumed as an argument in another statement. They **do not** embed. Which is what is said.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo shell is a pretty advanced MongoDB client.
It executes 2 queries for you in this case, not a single one.
As a proof, you can explore the execution plans, they will be equal(queries are formatted for readability):

```
db.getCollection('Forms')
    .find({"Id": { $nin: db.Forms.find({"Status": "DELETE" }, {_id:0, Id:1}).map(function (fr) { return fr.Id;} )}})
    .explain()
```

And

```
var excludedIds = db.Forms.find({"Status": "DELETE" }, {_id:0, Id:1}).map(function (fr) { return fr.Id;} )
db.getCollection('Forms')
    .find({"Id": { $nin: excludedIds }})
    .explain()
```

So you need to do the same in your client: first query `excludedIds`, then create a filter based on `excludedIds` and query `Forms` collection again.