# Mongodb aggregation:Passing arguments to custom function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my aggregation query

```
blockColctn.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "number": blockNumber
    }

    },
    {
    "$project": {
        "transactions.to": "$transactions.to",
        "transaction": "$transactions",
        "transactions.hash": "$transactions.hash",


    }
    },
    {
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "token_collections",
        "localField": "transactions.to",
        "foreignField": "tokencontractaddress",
        "as": "tokenaccount"
    }
    },
    {
    "$project": {
       "total":getTotal("transactions.hash")
    }
    }])
```

I am calling `getTotal` in `$project` it works fine, however, I would like to pass `transactions.hash` column value as the function argument.
I found a similar issue related to mine [Custom functions calculated columns mongodb projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620582/custom-functions-calculated-columns-mongodb-projection)

But it doesn't tell about argument passing

Comment: Where are you calling `blockColctn.aggregate()` from? You can create a composable function that takes in the aggregate and getTotal methods

Comment: Its from a function can you give an example??

Answer (score 2):

Would start by refactoring the above, first creating a function that takes in the column `total` value as the function argument and returns the pipeline array:

```
const getAggregatePipeline = total => ([
    { "$match": {
        "number": blockNumber
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "transactions.to": "$transactions.to",
        "transaction": "$transactions",
        "transactions.hash": "$transactions.hash",
    } },
    { "$lookup": {
        "from": "token_collections",
        "localField": "transactions.to",
        "foreignField": "tokencontractaddress",
        "as": "tokenaccount"
    } },
    { "$project": { total } }
])
```

Now you can pass this on to the aggregate method as

```
blockColctn.aggregate(getAggregatePipeline(getTotal("transactions.hash")))
```

As you can see we're just nesting functions inside each other so that when they're called with a final value, the result explodes outwards through each layer. This can be further refactored to create a composition of all those functions (i.e. that returns a new function) with the following blueprint

```
const compose = (f1, f2, f3) => value => f1( f2( f3(value) ) )
```

You can then call this as

```
const agg = compose(blockColctn.aggregate, getAggregatePipeline, getTotal)("transactions.hash")
```

---

For a compose function that’s fully variadic, i.e. one that can take an arbitrarily long list of functions and then work right to left (inner to outer):

```
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)))
```